# Copy a complete list on one spreadsheet to append on the bottom of another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet I would like to take only the values from a complete list on one spreadsheet and append it to the bottom of a list on another spreadsheet. My trouble is that using the the `copyValuesToRange()` function errors the following:

```
Target sheet and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.
```

Here's my current code:

```
function transferList() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ABCD"); 
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("RFPData");
  var sheet = source.getSheetByName("RFP List");
  var sheet_last_row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var source_range = sheet.getRange("A2:I"+sheet_last_row);
  var sWidth=source_range.getWidth() + 1;
  var sHeight=source_range.getHeight() + 1;
  var last_row=target_sheet.getLastRow();
  source_range.copyValuesToRange(target_sheet , 1, sWidth, 
    last_row + 1, last_row + sHeight );
}
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, `copyValuesToRange()` is a [Range method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#copyValuesToRange%28Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer%29) that affects a [Sheet Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) that is in the same [Spreadsheet Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) as the Range. There isn't an atomic method that will copy a range of values to another Spreadsheet, but there are a number of ways you could do it.

Here's one way.

- From the source sheet, get all the data in one operation, by selecting the complete range of data using `getDataRange()` and then grabbing all values into a javascript array with `getValues()`.
- To ignore the first row of headers, use the [javascript array method `splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
- Locate your destination, which is on the target sheet, starting after the last row of data that's currently there, using `getLastRow()`.
- Write the source data (without the headers) to the destination sheet starting at the next row, using `setValues()`.

Script:

```
function transferList() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RFP List");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(0,1);  // Remove header
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ABCD").getSheetByName("RFPData");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Comment: That function is transferring the header row, but none of the data.

Comment: Good catch - I tried to chain with splice, which yields the *removed* line instead of the *remainder*. Fixed now.

Comment: Well played, it's actually quite a bit shorter code than I expected too. Thanks!

Comment: +Mogsdad, regarding "There isn't an atomic method that will copy a range of values to another Spreadsheet"... if atomicity was important, could appendRow() provide it? Granted however, it can only do one row at a time.

Comment: @AdamL - copyValuesToRange works without requiring looping or intermediate storage. That's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

For some historic dashboard I created by importing and appending data, I use an add-on called Sheetgo. Save me programing time and help me with traceability issues.