# google script to export range to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to export a range of cells to another spreadsheet using a script? After the source range has been exported the source range will be cleared and manually repopulated.

Upon running of the script again the same range will be exported but added to the first export not overwrite the first export.

This would happen often, eventually compiling a large list of exported items.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Copy a complete list on one spreadsheet to append on the bottom of another spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044580/copy-a-complete-list-on-one-spreadsheet-to-append-on-the-bottom-of-another-sprea), there's a script there that should get you started.

Comment: Perfect and so easy. Thanks!