# Why can't I copy ranges between spreadsheets with copyValuesToRange()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am able to copy a range of values from one spreadsheet to another with [Range.setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) but not with [Range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)):

```
function test()
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceCols = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:B10");

  // Copying the first two columns this way works.
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Spreadsheet 1").getActiveSheet();
  sheet1.getRange("A1:B10").setValues(sourceCols.getValues());

  // Copying the first two columns this way does not work.
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Spreadsheet 2").getActiveSheet();
  sourceCols.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 1, 2, 1, 10);
}
```

Specifically, after running the code, `New Spreadsheet 1` contains range A1:B10 of the source spreadsheet, while `New Spreadsheet 2` is empty. Both have a single sheet named "Sheet1". The source spreadsheet is unmodified.

What am I doing wrong? I'm wondering if the failing method only works within a single spreadsheet, but I see nothing in the documentation about that.

The reason I want to use [Range.copyValuesToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) is so I can also copy the formatting with [Range.copyFormatToRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).

Comment: Is this will be helpful to you?  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044580/copy-a-complete-list-on-one-spreadsheet-to-append-on-the-bottom-of-another-sprea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044580/copy-a-complete-list-on-one-spreadsheet-to-append-on-the-bottom-of-another-sprea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `copyValuesToRange` and `copyFormatToRange`, as well as `Range.copyTo`, are restricted to copying within the same spreadsheets, although documentation is not explicit about that. A workaround which allows you to *copy between spreadsheets with formatting* is to copy the entire sheet to the destination spreadsheet, using [`Sheet.copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) method. Then copy the required range from there, and optionally, delete the sheet. Like this:

```
function cc() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('some url');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('another url');
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName('name');
  var sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName('another name');
     // the above was the setup, main code begins here
  var copySheet = sheet1.copyTo(ss2);
  copySheet.getRange("A1:B2").copyTo(sh2.getRange("C1:D2"));
  ss2.deleteSheet(copySheet);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice hack. I'll have to go through an additional step, since the source spreadsheet contains confidential information (student grades), but I could copy a slice to a temp sheet in the original, then copy the temp sheet to the new spreadsheet.