# Copy a list on one spreadsheet to append on the bottom of another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I know this topic was covered several years ago here: [Copy a complete list on one spreadsheet to append on the bottom of another spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044580/copy-a-complete-list-on-one-spreadsheet-to-append-on-the-bottom-of-another-sprea)

Here is the script:

```
function transferList() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RFP List");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(0,1);  // Remove header
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ABCD").getSheetByName("RFPData");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

But I'm trying to use this now and the last line of the script is not working for me. I get an error message saying "Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange."

I'm a total newbie and would be so grateful for help figuring out how to make this work. Also to make things simpler, I don't need to remove the header like they did using splice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function transferList() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("RFP List");
  const [hA,...vs1] = sh1.getDataRange().getValues();//array literal assignment the header array is still available for later use
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ABCD");
  const tsh = tss.getSheetByName("RFPData");
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1);
}
```